# ASP.NET dynamically added checkbox on masterpage and getting its postback on a childpage load

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, page-lifecycle, dynamic-controls

I have a dynamically created checkbox on my masterpage and checking/unchecking it causes a postback, my problem is I can't seem to get the value of the checkbox on the childpage because of the way the page lifecycle works with the childpage loading prior to the masterpage. I'm currently saving the checkbox value in a session value but because of the page lifecycle again the checkbox session value isn't updated until the masterpage loads so the childpages information is always a page behind so to speak.

Does anyone have some advice or know how I can get the postback data from the masterpage before loading the childpage when the checkbox checked event occurs on the masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `this.Master.FindControl("chkWhatever")`

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it yet but won't that return nothing as the controls don't exist on the masterpage yet as they were dynamically created and need to be recreated or is it smart enough to find that information from postback data?